# Java Swing Colour Chooser Throwing Error

Tags: java, swing, colors

So I'm trying to implement a colour chooser that will then take that colour and pass it to another class to be used, but it's throwing up the error

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   javax.swing.colorchooser.DefaultColorSelectionModel cannot be cast to
>   javax.swing.JColorChooser"

every time I click a colour.

The code I'm using is:

For the actual `JColorChooser`:

```
JColorChooser RGB = new JColorChooser(Color.GREEN);
RGB.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
RGB.setAlignmentX(newPolyButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
RGB.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50, 25));
RGB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(125, 25));
```

And for the listener:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent c) {
JColorChooser RGB = (JColorChooser)c.getSource();
Color poly = RGB.getColor();
imagePanel.setColor(poly);
}
```

And in the other class, `imagePanel`, I use:

```
public void setColor(Color poly) {
ImagePanel.poly = poly;
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going with this? I was previously using a combo box with some manually input colours to choose from.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code

```
RGB.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
RGB.setAlignmentX(newPolyButton.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

You are adding the ChangeListener to the Selection Modal for your RGB instance.

`javax.swing.JColorChooser.getSelectionModel()` will return an instance of `DefaultColorSelectionModel`.

Hence, you get a ClassCastException in your call `(JColorChooser)c.getSource();`.

**UPDATE**

From [How to Use Color Choosers Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html):

```
tcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
. . .
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    Color newColor = tcc.getColor();
    banner.setForeground(newColor);
}
```

When the state changes, you will want to get the new color as a property of the Color Chooser instead of attempting to get the Source of the ChangeEvent and cast it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, do you know how I'd go about fixing that? I'm not quite sure how to change it.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you how to fix it ... it's just with how you are referencing things.

Comment: Thanks! That was actually the tutorial I was using, but I guess I got the referencing mixed up a bit in trying to make it fit my code.

Comment: @Incredidave You're welcome.  The referencing is confusing for this particular Component ... I would instinctively also go after `e.getSource()` myself.

Answer (score 2):

In your `stateChanged` method, `c.getSource()` returns a `DefaultColorSelectionModel` and not the reference to your `JColorChooser`.

However, `JColorChooser` is usually used to open a color dialog that returns a `Color` when closed using the `OK` button.

```
Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(parent, title, initialColor);
if (color != null) {
  // do something with the chosen color
}
```

Comment: It's currently being used as just part of the interface, but a pop out dialog is probably a better idea, tbh.